# Recursividad suma de n numeros

Tags: python-3.x

tengo una duda con este método de programación.
Tengo que desarrollar una función recursiva que ingrese n números hasta que se ingrese el 0 y luego se sumen los números ingresados.
Más que me den el código, que me expliquen cómo hacerlo para entender la lógica

Comment: [Acá](https://www.online-python.com/ZXKQJq8bid) tienes un ejemplo con recursividad. No la respondo porque la verdad, no creo que se ajuste a las normas del sitio. De cualquier manera, siempre que puedas evitar la recursividad, evítala. La recursividad es lenta, y en python más todavía, aunque supongo sea algún ejercicio de clase.

Comment: Jaime; muchas gracias, me quedó clarísimo con el ejemplo que me dijiste, estaba con la duda cómo meter el input dentro. SOS grosso

Answer (score 0):

A ver si soy capaz:

```
sumar(N0 + N1 + N2 + N3 +......Nz)   
es como 
N0 + sumar(N1 + N2 + N3 +......Nz)   
Este último es lo mismo que    
     N1 + sumar(N2 + N3 +......Nz)   
Este último es lo mismo que    
          N2 + sumar(N3 +......Nz)   
...
...
Hasta que llegas a    
              sumar(Nz) que es Nz
```

En ese último devuelve el último valor a la última llamada y hace la suma, que devuelve un resultado a la anterior (y hace la suma) y así hasta llegar a la primera llamada.
Fíjate que en cada llamada recursiva el argumento es más "simple" hasta que es un solo número, es la condición de salida de esta especie de bucle o ciclo espiral.

Otra forma de verlo: tu sacas el primer valor y lo guardas para sumar luego, en la lista que te queda coges el primer valor y lo guardas para sumar luego, en la lista que queda coges el primer valor y lo guardas para sumar luego, la lista solo tienes un elemento lo devuelves.
Ahora ya vas como para atrás, ese último valor lo sumas a lo que guardaste en el penúltimo paso, este resultado lo sumas al número que guardaste en el paso anterior... así hasta llegar a la primera llamada a la función sumar.

El ejemplo típico de recursividad es el del factorial. Encontrarás miles de ejemplos con el factorial. También se usa para generar permutaciones, combinaciones, ordenaciones....

Comment: En el código al interior de la función def se debe añadir una variable de tipo lista?

Comment: En la respuesta, he intentado contestar a lo que pides: explicarte como es el proceso.  
Se puede hacer con la lista de números desde el principio.      
Y se puede hacer con el código que te han pasado, que en cada paso te pide un número para añadir a la suma.    
Depende del contexto como implementar el algoritmo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu función recursiva devolverá siempre un valor numerico y debe seguir la siguiente lógica (algoritmo):

```
funcion recursiva()
{
X <- leer_numero    // Cada vez que se invoca solicitas un número

Si X = 0
   retornar X      // Condición de parada de recursividad, este cero se suma en la llamada anterior si existe, pero no afectará el resultado
Sino
   retornar X + recursiva()   // Sumatoria:  Esta es una llamada recursiva
Fin Si
}
```

Toda función recursiva tiene al menos una condición de parada, para detener todas las llamadas posteriores recursivas.

No es recursiva, si la función no se invoca a si misma dentro de su definición.